# Grails noSelection property in the select tag over rides the value

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

I have the select tag below:

```
            <g:select name="recommendation" from="${recommendation.list()}"
                      optionKey="id" optionValue="recommendation"
                      value="${theAssessment.recommendation}"
                      noSelection="['':'-- Select Assessor Recommendation --']"
                      />
```

The form works as expected as when the value is null the noSelection is displayed. When I use the select tag to select the data I want to submit, this also works fine as this is persisted in the database. When I then go back to the form the noSelection over rides the value even when the value is not null. I've looked at the [docs](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/select.html) and I'm using this tag exactly as stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using optionKey="id" so that the Select value should be assigned as id.

```
   // I guess your Value should be id here     
       <g:select name="recommendation" from="${recommendation.list()}" optionKey="id" optionValue="recommendation"
                  value="${theAssessment?.recommendation?.id}"
                  noSelection="['':'-- Select Assessor Recommendation --']" />
```

If above code not work then try this.

```
       <g:select name="recommendation" from="${recommendation.list()}" 
              value="${theAssessment?.recommendation}"
              noSelection="['':'-- Select Assessor Recommendation --']" />
```

Comment: What does the '?' mean?

Comment: theAssessment?.recommendation?.id makes it null safe if (theAssessment) && if (theAssessment.recommendation) then show the id otherwise nothing and dont make it null

Comment: @CatChasedTheMouse http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_safe_navigation_operator