# Default value of dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, grails

Hello how can I set to this dropdown menu to have default value Second from the list?Here is the dropmenu

```
<g:select name="dropmenu" from="${["First", "Second", "Third"]}"
           />
```

Comment: Refer this question it shows how to set value for grails select [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585489](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585489/grails-noselection-property-in-the-select-tag-over-rides-the-value/38587784#38587784)

Answer (score 0):

```
<g:select selected="Second" name="dropmenu" from="${["First", "Second", "Third"]}"
       />
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded

[Set Default Text in a Select (drop-down) box/menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212939/set-default-text-in-a-select-drop-down-box-menu)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the value= attribute.  Below is an example that also shows the noSelection option for when the value is null.

```
            <g:select id="initialOutcome" name="initialOutcome.id" optionKey="id" from="${OutcomeDescription.findAll())}"
                  value="${outcome?.initialOutcome?.id}" noSelection="['':'-Select-']" class="form-control" title="Initial Outcome" required=""/>
```